# Other typologies of brackets using spalign package

Tags: math-mode, macros, packages, delimiters

If I have this MWE created with [spalign](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spalign) package,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{spalign}

\begin{document}

\[ \def\spalignendline{\cr}
\spalignrun{\bordermatrix{\the\spaligntoks}}
{, a b; A -1 -2; B -4 4} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

> What is the procedure to have vertical, squared, `{ }`, brackets for the matrices?

At the pag. 6 there is the procedure,

[image]

but I am not able to adapt it with my code.

Comment: I'd try `delims=\lbrack\rbrack`

Comment: @egreg My "tallone d'Achille" is the English language :-( and often the syntetic explanation for specific documentation. Thank you very much to you and all users. I am glad to receive an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that `\bordermatrix` is actually influenced by the setting of the `delims` option.

Indeed, the code

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[delims=\lbrack\rbrack]{spalign}

\begin{document}

\[\spalignmat{1 2;3 4}\]

\[ \def\spalignendline{\cr}
\spalignrun{\bordermatrix{\the\spaligntoks}}
{, a b; A -1 -2; B -4 4} \]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

This is because `\bordermatrix` is not governed by `spalign`, but is a LaTeX kernel command (and actually a port of plain TeX).

You may be luckier with `nicematrix`, of which I like the syntax much better.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, first-col]
  &  a &  b \\
A & -1 & -2 \\
B & -4 &  4
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely that nicematrix is better of spalign....just my it was a curiosity. I never will have thinked to put `delims=\lbrack\rbrack` in `\usepackage[delims=\lbrack\rbrack]{spalign}`. Thank you lot lot lot....to you. And all the best to you and the all users.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `\spalignrun` just produces the tokens (`\the\spaligntoks`) inside the matrix, not the delimiters itself.  So you just need to invoke some border-matrix software that allows convenient reset of the delimiters.  First one I found was `kbordermatrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{spalign}

\begin{document}

\[ \def\spalignendline{\cr}
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{\langle}
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{|}
\spalignrun{\kbordermatrix{\the\spaligntoks}}
{, a b; A -1 -2; B -4 4} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]